# How to test Nodejs request callback listener?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I use jest for unit test. my code is

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let request = http.request(options, resp => {
    resp.setEncoding('utf-8');
    let body = '';
    resp.on('data', chunk => {
      body += chunk
    });
    resp.on('error', error => {
      body += error;
      reject(body, resp);
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      this.end(method, resp, url, body, data, opts)
        .then(body => {
          resolve(body, resp);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err, resp);
        });
    });
  });
  request.end();
```

I use mock variable by `jest.fn()` but it needs to `EventEmitter` object for second parameter of `request` function which is `resp`.
after call `request` function `end` event listener will call. 
I want to execute `data` and `error` event listener but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official [Mock functions documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html), especially the [mock-implementations part](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-implementations). You can also find several tutorials such as [Unit Testing Beginners Guide - Part 3 - Mock Http And Files access](https://www.jstwister.com/post/unit-testing-beginners-guide-mock-http-and-files/) on the web.

Comment: Thanks. In your first link it's mock whole request function which has http.get(). my problem is how to test data and err event listener of http.requet() second parameter.

Comment: For second link I dont know how to port it in node environment for requet method. can you show me an example

Comment: I do not see the point testing the 'data' or 'error' callbacks, I think you should mock the whole http.request function in order to check the edge cases returned values for your code (eg. final success & error bodies). You can also look at [nock module](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) to fully mock the http API.